# PhD in finance/econ vs PhD in mathematics

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I earned a Bachelor's and Master's degree in finance. Eight years later I am thinking of going back to school to earn my PhD. I am currently a high school math teacher but I want to be a professor at the university level, so I want to do a PhD. The question is which one is easier and faster? Finance, economics, or mathematics? I know finance and economics require less math and more practical experience and knowledge of business and economics culture (which is something I am lacking). On the other hand, finance and economics are in-demand fields. Has anyone been through the same experience? Please advise, thank you.

Comment: I'll guess none are faster or easier. Just different. Think about what you want to do before you choose a path to get "somewhere". You have more background in finance, but how has that worked out for you if you are teaching secondary math?

Comment: Having went through a PhD program in math, what I can say is that it will be hard to jump into a math PhD program unless you have a pretty good math preparation.  For example, did you take a number of proof-based courses in mathematics as an undergraduate or masters student?  Did you take real analysis (usually a year long, always proof based)?  If not, it'll be really, really hard to be successful in a PhD program until you've done that.  Also, think about what kind of research you want to be doing as a PhD student since that research really defines the degree.

Comment: Thank you, Buffy and Travis, for your advice. It is very helpful. What I know is to become a professor at university, but in what subject! this what I am trying to figure out. I feel very comfortable and in love with teaching Mathematics (Alg2, trigonometric, calculus,..). I think my best fit is in Economics. Thank you all for your time and support.

Answer (score 3):

These are incredibly differently fields, and I feel like you should gain a much firmer grasp of these differences before looking into PhD programs in any.  It's also meaningless to consider which field is "harder", since there will be huge variation between different programs within each field, and between how individuals experience those fields.

Finance and econ USE a lot of math, but they aren't math degrees.  Between these two I would at least recommend econ over finance *unless* you know for certain that you want to work/research in finance.  Most econ degrees include some work in finance, along side other econ areas, so you can cast a broader net while still learning what interests you.  In my experience the majority of econ PhD programs require no practical experience, and in fact skew very heavily toward theory.  Econ is also not necessarily related to business - there are a lot of specialties under the "economics" umbrella.

Also, I think it's great your goal is to teach (I also like teaching), but your PhD will be very heavily focused on doing original research.  Do you also enjoy this?  Consider that strongly before embarking on this path, because completing your degree will hinge almost entirely on you being able to sustain a multi-year research project, while practically not at all on your ability to teach.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff for your recommendation, it is really helpful. What I meant by easier of harder is that I had the background and skills for either Finance or Eco.